# How to manage anxiety just before flying?

Tags: airplane

I am new to aviation and flying.
I have a one hour trip that is making me anxious and sleepless.

How can I manage the fear and is it safe or just like the news we hear on news?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to Travel.SE

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Take a look at this on Travel.SE: [Are there tips and tricks to overcome a fear of flying?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22736/are-there-tips-and-tricks-to-overcome-a-fear-of-flying?r=SearchResults) Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal to have anxiety when experiencing something new.  These "butterflies" of the stomach are your body's reaction to your minds confusion over a new situation.

This is where training and mental discipline are key.  Rationalize what is making you uncomfortable and focus on your task.

Looking down at my landing gear while flying along at 2000 feet somehow made me more nervous, so I learned to focus on the horizon and to calm down.

Put what is bothering you aside as best you can.  With experience, your mind will differentiate and sort out what should be making you nervous (losing a wing), from what should not.  Then your body will not react (by being nervous) to normal aspects of flying (departing, cruising, landing).  Enjoy the view!

Comment: +1 for the rather heartless remark. I just don't understand the trigger happy itch to close posts among some commentators.

Comment: @curious_cat The question appears to be about flying as a passenger, rather than as a pilot (because it's a while before you get to fly solo).

Comment: Thanks Robert you've made me better.

Comment: @curious_cat: Because it's not really a question about flying.  It's a psychological question that could apply to any new experience.  Certainly I was a bit nervous the first time I rode a horse, for instance, and if I could remember that far back, probably the first time I drove a car, rode a bike, went skiing...